# Spring 3.x + SimpleJdbcTemplate : Returning multiple columns

Tags: java, spring, spring-3, spring-jdbc

I am using `SimpleJdbcTemplate` with `Spring 3.x`. For getting a single column, I use the below code and it works fine:

```
public String selectSingleColumn(int deptId){
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT DEPT_NAME FROM DEPT WHERE DEPT_ID = ?", String.class, deptId);
}
```

**Problem:**

I want to fetch multiple columns such as `DEPT_NAME` and `DEPT_CODE` from that above table (but not all that belong to the table), how to modify the above code to get it done? I am confused with the `second parameter` of the `queryForObject` in this case; ideally I think it should be `Object[]` but stilll confused. Please guide me.

Comment: Why don't you query for the entire domain object, instead of writing several queries for a different combination of columns. It makes more sense, and make the dao more reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just query for an entire domain object, instead of having to write different queries for different columns. For one, it makes the dao more reusable.

For example:

Department domain object

```
public class Department {
    private long id;
    private String deptName;
    private String deptCode;
    // other fields

    // getters and setters
}
```

DepartmentDao

```
public class DepartmentDaoImpl extends JdbcTemplate implements DepartmentDao {

    private static final String DEPT_BY_ID 
                          = "select * from DEPARTMENT where DEPT_ID = ?";

    @Override
    public Department getDepartmentById(long id) {
        return (Department) queryForObject(
             DEPT_BY_ID, 
             new Object[] { id },
             new RowMapper<Department>() {
                 @Override
                 public Department mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNumber) {
                     Department dept = new Department();
                     dept.setId(rs.getLong("DEPT_ID");
                     dept.setDeptName(rs.getString("DEPT_NAME");
                     dept.setDeptCode(rs.getString("DEPT_CODE");
                     // set other properties

                     return dept;
                 }
             });
    }
}
```

If you really, really only want two columns,  you could use `queryForMap`

```
public class TestCustomerDao extends JdbcTemplate implements DepartmentDao {

    private static final String FOR_MAP 
                = "select DEPT_NAME,DEPT_CODE from DEPARTMENT where DEPT_ID = ?";

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getCoupleColumnsById(long id) {
        return (Map<String, Object>)queryForMap(FOR_MAP, new Object[] {id});
    }
}
```

The map will return as

```
   key        value
DEPT_NAME  =  value
DEPT_CODE  =  value
```

Comment: Any specific reasons for using `jdbctemplate`? I am new to spring and AFAIK, it is replaced by `SimpleJdbcTemplate`. Please advice

Comment: [`SimpleJdbcTemplate` is deprecated as of 3.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/). It was originally made as a wrapper for the `JdbcTemplate` but then most of the commonly used methods from `SimpleJdbcTemplate` were brought to `JdbcTemplate`

Answer (score -1):

Given below are the steps  to do this -

**(1) Create a domain Object for Department**

```
public class Department{
    private String departmentName;
    private String departmentCode;
    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

**(2) Create a RowMapper class to map the result set to the Department Object**

```
public class DepartmentRowMapper implements RowMapper<Department>
{
    public Department mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Department department= new Department ();
        department.setDepartmentName(rs.getString("DEPT_NAME"));
        department.setDepartmentCode(rs.getString("DEPT_CODE"));
        return department;
    }

}
```

**(3) Create the Dao class**

```
public class DepartmentDao
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 
   //getters and setters omitted for brevity 
   public Department getDepartment(int deptId){
    return (Department)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT DEPT_NAME FROM DEPT WHERE DEPT_ID = ?",new Object[] {deptId}, new DepartmentRowMapper ());
   }
}
```

Comment: Creating a domain object for only this single query? What if in other case I need another couple of columns from Department table?